# CSS3 animation: rotateX to flip more than two divs

Tags: html, animation, transform, css-transitions, flip

I currently have the following HTML and CSS which creates the effect of flipping between the content of two divs.

How I can expand on this to flip between 4 (or more) divs?

I was thinking either of these approaches might be the way forward but I'm not sure how to implement them!

- pause the animations at `rotateX(90deg)` then start a second set of animations;
- or change the content of the divs when they are at `rotateX(90deg)`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="flip1">
  FLIP 1<br />
  FLIP 1<br />
  FLIP 1<br />
  FLIP 1<br />
</div>
<div class="flip2">
  FLIP 2<br />
  FLIP 2<br />
  FLIP 2<br />
  FLIP 2<br />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    color: blue;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip1 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg); }
}

div.flip1 {
    -webkit-animation-name: flip1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip2 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
}

div.flip2 {
    -webkit-animation-name: flip2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got there in the end with a touch of JavaScript.

The HTML was:

```
<div class="flippable" id="flip1">
  FLIP 1<br />
  FLIP 1<br />
  FLIP 1<br />
  FLIP 1<br />
</div>
<div class="flippable" id="flip2">
  FLIP 2<br />
  FLIP 2<br />
  FLIP 2<br />
  FLIP 2<br />
</div>
<div class="flippable" id="flip3">
  FLIP 3<br />
  FLIP 3<br />
  FLIP 3<br />
  FLIP 3<br />
</div>
<div class="flippable" id="flip4">
  FLIP 4<br />
  FLIP 4<br />
  FLIP 4<br />
  FLIP 4<br />
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  flip_flippables();
  setInterval(flip_flippables, $('.flippable').length*2000);
  function flip_flippables(){
    $('.flippable').each(function(index) {
        setTimeout(function(thisObj) { thisObj.addClass("flippedforward"); }, index*2000, $(this));
        $(this).removeClass("flippedforward");
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

The CSS was:

```
.flippable {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    color: blue;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

.flippedforward {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-name: flip;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg); }
    25% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); }
    75% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg); }
}
```